# Pushing snapshot with same version many times to Clojars

Tags: clojure, clojars

I've been pushing a library (with same version) several times to clojars. Previously, every time I builded the project, leiningen fetched the latest snapshot:

`[my-library "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]`

But now I have to write its version explicitly in the project.clj dependencies, in order to get the latest snapshot, like this:

`[my-library "0.1.0-20150415.183412-9"]`

I guess I just could change the library version to `"0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"`. But, if anyone could just explain me why I can't get the latest snapshot like before.

Thanks

Comment: IIRC, Leiningen caches SNAPSHOTs sometimes. Have you tried `lein -U deps` to force the update?

Comment: @xsc Nope, didn't do it...

Comment: What's the library in question? There was a bug in clojars from Monday to yesterday that prevented storing the maven-metadata.xml for a re-written snapshot. Without that, lein can't find the proper version. You should be able to redeploy a snapshot of the lib today and fix the problem.

Comment: @TobyCrawley [full-control "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]

Comment: @roboli - it looks like the versions pushed on the 14th and 15th weren't able to update the metadata (it still shows `0.1.0-20150314.010023-8` as the latest). Can you deploy the snapshot again? That should fix the problem.